# Cakephp paginate link to method in Model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I would like to get any help. I want to code pagination in Controller which can be retrieve the data from method in Model. Notice I use cakephp.

This is function uploadDocumentForm in Controller

```
function uploadDocumentForm()
        {
                if(!$this->User->checkPrivilege(array(6))) {
                        throw new ForbiddenException();
                }
                $userID = $this->Session->read('userID');
                $this->set('documentList',$this->SystemParameter->getDocumentList("DOCUMENT_TYPE"));
                $this->set('studentUploadDocumentList',$this->Document->getDocumentByUserID($userID));
```

This is getDocumentByUserID function in Document Model

```
function getDocumentByUserID($anUserID)
        {
                return $this->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Project.student_user_id'=>$anUserID),'order'=>array('Document.document_id'=>'desc')));
        }
```

So, how I can code the pagination in Controller linked to getDocumentByUserID?
Thank you very much

Ponom

Comment: What is your actual question? I don't really understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Here is my question ? I miss typing. How I can code the pagination in Controller linked to getDocumentByUserID?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered [in the chapter about the pagination component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination) in the official documentation, read it.

> If you’re not able to use the standard find options to create the
>   query you need to display your data, there are a few options. You can
>   use a custom find type. You can also implement the paginate() and
>   paginateCount() methods on your model, or include them in a behavior
>   attached to your model. Behaviors implementing paginate and/or
>   paginateCount should implement the method signatures defined below
>   with the normal additional first parameter of $model: